# PowerBI grouping issue

Tags: powerbi

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to do this task.

I have 18 duplicate pm_id for a task and if any of those 18 fail in the value column then the whole thing fails.  Would it be best to create a new column or a measure?  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: data]

Comment: it depends on what you need to do with this information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data source and what you want to do with this result? If the global result is the same whatever the filters, you need a new colum. Or even better a new table with pm_id and global result to avoid duplicating the data on each row is a good way to model this.

If you just need to display the value, and it may be changed depending on the filters. A measure is the good way to do it.

Comment: I need to know how many pass or fail. There could be 100s of different pm_ids for the same location and if any of the column pm_template_taks fails then the whole pm fails.